# Travel with a baby from Eindhoven to Maasbree in the Netherlands

Tags: children, netherlands, taxis, child-safety-seats

We are flying from London into [Eindhoven](http://www.eindhovenairport.com/) in the Netherlands and then traveling to [Maasbree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maasbree) (about 40 minutes by car) for the weekend. A friend has arranged for a taxi but we'll have a baby with us and we don't have a car seat. Are there taxis available with car seats? Is there other transport to consider? Would it be possible to borrow or hire a car seat either in the Netherlands or in London? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't think we have taxis with car seats available in the netherlands.

Comment: @Jacco - That's what my dutch friend said!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Public transport is comfortable and easy in the Netherlands, and a good way to experience the country. You will need to change several times, which is always a bit of trouble with a baby, but it won't be worse than going through the airports. Do mind how far your destination in Maasbree is from the bus stop — though it might be easier to arrange a bike with a baby seat than a car!

You can find a complete itinerary on the [9292ov journey planner](http://journeyplanner.9292.nl/). The most likely itinerary is bus 401 from Eindhoven airport to Eindhoven station, then a train to Venlo and a bus to Maasbree. The journey time is about 1:30. That is admittedly significantly slower than driving. The trains from Eindhoven (platform 2) to Venlo run every half-hour. See the [NS website](http://ns.nl/). You can book in advance and print tickets at home. The tickets are valid for one day (for a single journey), so you don't need to figure out the exact time in advance.

On the bus, you pay with an electronic purse on a dedicated smart card (similar to London's Oyster Card), the [OV-chipkaart](http://www.ov-chipkaart.nl/?taal=en). [Buying an OV-chipkaart can be a little difficult without a Dutch banking card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/recharging-an-ov-chipkaart-without-a-dutch-banking-card); hopefully you can get one (per person) at the airport, but I can't find any confirmation.

From Venlo, bus 61 or 62 brings you to [Maasbree](http://www.peelenmaas.nl/index.php?mediumid=11&pagid=1373).

Comment: +1 Good answer and thanks for the links. I've selected this as the accepted answer despite going a different route.

Answer (score 5):

You could get a taxi from Eindhoven airport into the city centre, and then [catch a train to Blerick](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&authuser=0&hl=en&geocode=&q=Maasbree,+The+Netherlands&aq=0&vps=1&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=55.937499,79.013672&vpsrc=0&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Maasbree,+Peel+en+Maas,+Limburg,+The+Netherlands). It would then be another short taxi ride to get to Maasbree. Perhaps this is an option?

Comment: We'll actually be in Blerick/Venlo for part of the weekend. Is it possible to get a taxi with a car seat? Or is it like in London where you can roll a pram into a black cab?

Answer (score 3):

We ended up borrowing a car seat. In asking around to find a place we could hire one, we found a friend that could loan us one for the weekend. This turned out to be the best option as we can travel with the arranged taxis with the rest of the group. I just want to add these options as an answer.

1. Borrow from a friend - Ask friends or at baby groups. There is a good chance of finding a car seat especially for a short trip.
2. [Freecycle](http://www.freecycle.org/) - A group of people that give and get stuff for free. Children's items are commonly exchanged as they are typically outgrown before they are worn out.
3. [ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/) - There were plenty of car seats listed on ebay with some less than £10.